# Templated struct should contain subtype, but compiler says it doesn't

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to play around with C++ metaprogramming and everything was going fairly well, except when I try to compile this reproducer:

```
struct _0 {
  template<typename F, typename X>
  using apply = X;
};

struct Z {
  template<typename F>
  struct impl {
    struct C {
      template<typename X>
      struct closure {
        template<typename V>
        struct impl {
          // Broken out to help with debugging
          using XX = typename X::template apply<X>;
          using XXV = typename XX::template apply<V>;
        };
        template<typename V>
        using apply = typename impl<V>::XXV;
      };
      template<typename X>
      using apply = typename F::template apply<closure<X>>;
    };
    using exec = typename C::template apply<C>;
  };
  template<typename F>
  using apply = typename impl<F>::exec;
};

struct True {
  template<typename Consequent, typename Alternative>
  using apply = Consequent;
};

struct False {
  template<typename Consequent, typename Alternative>
  using apply = Alternative;
};

struct zero {
  struct constantly_false {
    template<typename>
    using apply = False;
  };

  template<typename N>
  using apply = typename N::template apply<constantly_false, True>;
};

struct mintest {
  template<typename F>
  struct closure {
    template<typename N>
    using apply =
      typename zero::apply<N>::template apply<
      _0, typename F::template apply<_0>>;
  };
  template<typename F>
  using apply = closure<F>;
};
using test = Z::apply<mintest>;

using F = test::apply<_0>;

int main() {
  return 0;
};
```

I end up getting the errors:

```
reproducer.cc: In instantiation of ‘struct Z::impl<mintest>::C::closure<Z::impl<mintest>::C>::impl<_0>’:
reproducer.cc:19:44:   required by substitution of ‘template<class F> template<class X> template<class V> using apply = typename Z::impl<F>::C::closure<X>::impl::XXV [with V = _0; X = Z::impl<mintest>::C; F = mintest]’
reproducer.cc:56:42:   required from ‘struct mintest::closure<Z::impl<mintest>::C::closure<Z::impl<mintest>::C> >’
reproducer.cc:63:15:   required from here
reproducer.cc:16:53: error: no class template named ‘apply’ in ‘using XX = Z::impl<mintest>::C::apply<Z::impl<mintest>::C> {aka struct mintest::closure<Z::impl<mintest>::C::closure<Z::impl<mintest>::C> >}’
           using XXV = typename XX::template apply<V>;
```

Which make no sense to me. There are no specializations of mintest::closure so every instantiation should, I'd think, have apply in it. I tried with Clang and got the same error, which was my clue that there was just something i don't understand.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, `XX` is not a template.

Comment: It doesn't need to be. (I only broke XX and XXV out to better localize the error). XX just has to evaluate to something that contains an apply template.

Comment: The problem is that `using apply = typename impl<F>::exec;` (inside `Z`) is an instantiated template at that point.  Change this to `using apply = F;` and it compiles.  However, I have no idea what this code should do, so I cannot really post a solution.

Comment: Did you examine `struct mintest::closure<Z::impl<mintest>::C::closure<Z::impl<mintest>::C> >`?  Like normal programming, to debug metaprogramming you have to len how to step through your code, write type checks, and do sanity checks.  Something this complex is like a pile of `void*` stored untyped data being blindly cast and passed around and being surpriaed that it doesn't do something; the surprising thing would be it working!